# users going to error page rather than instance version of a record

Tags: force.com, single-sign-on

I'm implementing SSO with SAML in our org. I'm thinking about a case where a user is not set up for SSO in SF gets a link begining with my domain. since their federation id is not entered, they shouldn't have sso privileges. the issue is what happens next. They are getting sent to an error page, or a custom page that i can define (I don't think I can define this at run time. right now it's just test.salesforce.com).

I want to send the user to the instance version of that page. of course they'd have to login, but they should be able to go where they were intending. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this case won't happen, **so long as you don't deploy your domain**.  the way this works apparently is that you give your user your  the "my domain friendly link." then you have the user log in to SF. When the log in is complete, he sees the instance in the URL, not the my domain. He'd have to go out of his way to append a record to the my domain friendly link. at which point it would bomb out.